# Xamarin: Different appxmanifest files for different build configurations

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I want to use different Package.appxmanifest files for some build configurations. I cannot include more than one appxmanifest-file into my Xamarin-UWP project.
And ideas like doing it like Android also doesn't work:

Working for multiple AndroidManifest files:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-CH|AnyCPU'">
…
<AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifestCH.xml</AndroidManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How can I achive this for UWP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And ideas like doing it like Android also doesn't work

According to [**App package manifest**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest), Every app package must include one package manifest. If you create a new appxmanifest file in the uwp, it will throw error like the follow.

> The project contains 2 items that represent the app manifest: Package.appxmanifest,  Test.appxmanifest. The project can contain only one app manifest

If you do want to use different `Package.appxmanifest` files for some build configurations. you could edit `FileGuidTest.csproj` manually.

Right Click Project-> Unload Project-> Re-Right Click Project-> Edit Project.csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </AppxManifest>
  <AppxManifest Include="app.appxmanifest">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </AppxManifest>
  <None Include="FileGuidTest_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  <AppxManifest Include="Test.appxmanifest">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </AppxManifest>
</ItemGroup>
```

Find out the above `ItemGroup` node and reserve only one `AppxManifest`. And then modify the follow PropertyGroup node.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ApplicationManifest>Package.appxmanifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I added in about 10 PropertyGroups: <ApplicationManifest>Package.appxmanifest</ApplicationManifest> ... and in the one with the wanted condition: <ApplicationManifest>PackageCH.appxmanifest</ApplicationManifest> ... additional I added both files in an ItemGroup (that isn't part of any of the PropertyGropus): <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">...

Comment: Both `ItemGroup` and `PropertyGroup` have only one element.

Comment: That seems to work. But although the PackageCH.appxmanifest is not part of an ItemGroup (but in one PropertyGroup), it is shown as a project file in the visual tree view of the project.